# calculating the residue for the following complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the residue for $b$, and I never can get the answer after plugging in the roots, can someone help me out?

$$a=(-3 + \sqrt{5})/2\text{ and }b=(-3 - \sqrt{5})/2$$

$${z/((z-a)^2(z-b)^2)}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula for the residue around a pole of order n? Plug your formula and singularity in the formula given over here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles. I haven't done the calculation but it seems like it should go through without any problems. If you're using this correctly and still not getting the correct answer maybe show us the details of your work?

Comment: See directions in the FAQ section to use LaTeX to properly write mathematics in this site: your expressions are tough to understand, and there's a weird line jump that makes things tougher...

Comment: I changed a=(-3 + $\sqrt{5}$)/2 to $a=(-3 + \sqrt{5})/2$.  The former is weird; the latter is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Elaborating on what Ahsan said, you can use $$
    \mathrm{Res}(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( (z-c)^{n}f(z) \right). \tag{1} $$
when you have a singularity of order $\ge 2$.

I am assuming your poles are: $$a=(-3 + \sqrt{5})/2\text{ and }b=(-3 - \sqrt{5})/2?$$ If it is, then just take the limit of each and calculate the residues from there. For example, $$\lim_{z\to \frac{(-3 - \sqrt{5})}{2}} = \frac{d}{dz} \frac{z}{(z-a)^2}= \ ...$$
**S.N:** There is a $\frac{d}{dz}$ in the limit because I used the formula above noted $(1)$.

So we have $$\lim_{z\to \frac{(-3 - \sqrt{5})}{2}}= \frac{a+z}{(a-z)^3}= \frac{\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{(-3 - \sqrt{5})}{2}}{(\frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{(-3 - \sqrt{5})}{2})^3} =\frac{\frac{-6}{2}}{(\frac{2\sqrt5}{2})^3}=\frac{-3}{(\sqrt5)^3} \tag{2}$$
and then do the same for the other pole by taking the limit and applying the same procedure I did with $(2)$. When you get that, add the two limits and multiply be $2\pi i$.

Comment: I know the following formulas, I was hoping you plugged them in because that was where I had trouble

Comment: @DJ_ Editing right now, give me a few more minutes.

Comment: @DJ_ What is your original integral before you got ${z/((z-a)^2(z-b)^2)}$?

Comment: No what you have is right, thanks!

Comment: No problem :) !